# Directive for custom fields in form [scope is not updating]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a directive for custom fields in the form. I am able to create directive but not able to update scope.

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z94hckQhOKmQud2460NC?p=preview) demo for more idea about problem

**Issue** I am facing is when I am submitting the form I am getting a value of custom field ng-model is null or undefined. because **Two Way Binding** is not working

you will see when we update scope from the parent it will update directive scope but when you will update it in a custom field it will not update input field which is using parent scope and after that two way binding will not work

Here are my files

**users.html**

```
<custom-field ng-repeat="(key,field) in custom_fields" form="userForm" ng-model="user.custom_field[field.id]" fielddata="field"></custom-field>
```

**app.js**

```
app.directive('customField', function () {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.templateUrl = 'app/modules/custom_fields/views/custom_field_directive.html';
    directive.scope = {
        ngModel: "=",
        mydata: "<fielddata",
        form: "<"
    }

    return directive;
});
```

**custom_field_directive.html**

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex >
        <!-- Custom input field html [Required Field]  -->
        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="mydata.type == 'input' && mydata.is_required==1">
            <label>{{mydata.field_name}}</label>
            <input name="{{mydata.slug}}" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="!ngModel"> 
            <div ng-messages="form[''+mydata.slug+''].$error" ng-show="form[''+mydata.slug+''].$touched" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="required">
                    <span>{{mydata.field_name}} is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <!-- Custom input field html  -->
        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="mydata.type == 'input' && mydata.is_required==0">
            <label>{{mydata.field_name}}</label>
            <input name="phone" ng-model="ngModel"> 
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function for getting custom fields values from database **UsersController.js**

```
$scope.getCustomFields = function (id = "") {
        $rootScope.loader = true;
        $http.post(site_settings.api_url + 'get_custom_fields_admin_user', {id: id})
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.custom_fields = response.data;
                    angular.forEach($scope.custom_fields, function (value, key) {
                        if (value.field_values) {
                            $scope.user.custom_field[value.id] = value.field_values.value;
                            console.log("in");
                        } else {
                            $scope.user.custom_field[value.id] = null;
                        }
                    });
                    $rootScope.loader = false;
                }).catch(function (error) {
            $rootScope.message = 'Something Went Wrong.';
            $rootScope.$emit("notification");
            $rootScope.loader = false;
        });
    }
```

Here is my user model which I get at submitting form

[image: Response]

**Demo**

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z94hckQhOKmQud2460NC?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your answer @jack.

The child scope is created by `ngIf`.

You can use `ngShow` `ngHide` or `ngWhen` instead and solve the scoping problem.

Generally, you should avoid calling `$parent` as much as you can.

Whenever you come across a situation where `$parent` fixes the problem, it most probably a problem with your scope or a wrong design

You can see about `ngIf` scope in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

here is the relevant part:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right, I also tried and it is working but I don't know why it is not exactly working. so i used $parent. Thanks for this explanation

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

It was creating child scope, just changed **custom_field_directive.html** ngModle to $parent.ngModel

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex >
        <!-- Custom input field html [Required Field]  -->
        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="mydata.type == 'input' && mydata.is_required==1">
            <label>{{mydata.field_name}}</label>
            <input name="{{mydata.slug}}" ng-model="$parent.ngModel" ng-required="!ngModel"> 
            <div ng-messages="form[''+mydata.slug+''].$error" ng-show="form[''+mydata.slug+''].$touched" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="required">
                    <span>{{mydata.field_name}} is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <!-- Custom input field html  -->
        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="mydata.type == 'input' && mydata.is_required==0">
            <label>{{mydata.field_name}}</label>
            <input name="phone" ng-model="$parent.ngModel"> 
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```